# Querying from multiple linked Excel files

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I currently have linked multiple Excel files to Access (one file for each month) and I want to create a query from each file that will give me a "master query."  All the files are exactly the same with the headings and format.  I cannot merge all three and then link because it is well over the Excel Maximum.

I tried this and it gives me the error `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`

```
  SELECT [Created Date], [Store Name], ProductID, [Customer First Name] & " " & [Customer Last Name] AS CustomerName
  FROM August2015
  WHERE ProductID = 1587996 OR ProductID = 1587985 
  UNION
  SELECT [Created Date], [Store Name], ProductID, [Customer First Name] & " " & [Customer Last Name] AS CustomerName
  FROM July2015
  WHERE ProductID = 1587996 OR ProductID = 1587985 
  UNION
  SELECT [Created Date], [Store Name], ProductID, [Customer First Name] & " " & [Customer Last Name] AS CustomerName
  FROM June2015
  WHERE ProductID = 1587996 OR ProductID= 1587985
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like ProductID is a string. If so:

```
WHERE ProductID = '1587996' OR ProductID = '1587985'
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. But yet I missed that. Thank you!